# wagmi useContractWrite response not including event parameters

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, smart-contract, wagmi

I am using wagmi `useContractWrite` hook to execute a smart contract function and would like to capture the response from the function emitted through an event. The event seems to be captured under data.logs and the event arguments/params are included in the `logs[0].data` field but the named arguments/params are not there. Is there something additional that needs to be done to capture the event parameters or I have to somehow parse the individual params from the full string in logs[0].data.

The highlighted section in data string is the first parameter of the event and the rest are appended after that.

Here is a screenshot of the response data object from the `useContractWrite`.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse the individual parameters from the `logs[0].data` field as it contains the encoded data of the event and not the named parameters.

You can read more here:
https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/utils/abi/coder/

Example Code:

```
/* some more code here */

// define signature and hash
const eventSignature = 'YourEvent(uint256, string)';
const eventSignatureHash = ethers.utils.id(eventSignature);

/* some more code here */

// check topics for your event
if (logs.topics[0] === eventSignatureHash) {
      const decodedEvent = ethers.utils.defaultAbiCoder.decode(
        [
          'uint256',
          'string'
        ],
        logs[0].data
      );
      // console decoded data
      console.log(decodedEvent);
}
```

Example demo `console.log()` output of `decodedEvent`:

```
[ 123, 'hello world' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Wagmi, you don't have to go through complex procedure of decoding transaction logs. You could simply utilize **Wagmi's** `useContractEvent({})` hook as well as `useContractWrite({})` to handle events.

The hook's structure is as below:

```
  useContractEvent({
     address: 'Your Contract Address',
     abi: 'You Contract ABI',
     eventName: 'Name of Your Event',
     listener(parameter1, parameter2, parameter3) {
       console.log(parameter1, parameter2, parameter3)
     },
  })
```

Give its documentation a read, and modify this hook according to your needs:

https://wagmi.sh/react/hooks/useContractEvent